# excel_sheets produces: Error: `path` does not exist: ‘AE800’ but rstudio has the file saved in my environment and I can open file

Tags: r

I am still new to R and I am not sure if I am missing something simple. I can open the excel file in R and it displays only the first tab/sheet. I know the path exists because I have the file currently on R and I copied the path right from the "copy path" option on the document. The file is also in my set working directory. Image of rstudio below. Thank you.

[image: Picture of screen]

Comment: Take the quotes off the R object name. excelsheets was apparently trying to find a path rather than a connection. You should explain why you wanted to use `excel_sheets` when you alreay have an R data object with the information.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Without the quotes It produces: Error: `path` must be a string

Comment: It would also be easier if you could transform your excel table into a csv one. Then you could use read.csv or read.csv2. I also recommand you to create project and put your data in this project file. You can then access it using the path "./yourfilename.csv".

Comment: `excel_sheets`'s argument is also a `path`, so it needs to be the `"C:\\Users\\spice\\..."`, same as the previous call. In a general sense, I would expect to look at the sheet names _before_ loading from the workbook, not after ... though that's just my "exploratory process" preference. The `read_excel` function can take `sheet=` as an argument, which can be the name of the sheet or an integer (position of the sheet). If you have `shnms <- excel_sheets("C:\\.....")`, you could do something like `allsheets <- lapply(shnms, function(nm) read_excel("C:\\......", sheet=nm))` (for a list of frames)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this workflow instead:

```r
path <- "C:\\Users\\spice\\......." # use your real path here
shnms <- sheet_names(path)
alldata <- lapply(shnms, function(nm) read_excel(path, sheet=nm))
```

and you'll get a named `list`, each element is a worksheet in the original workbook.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not actually interested in getting the sheet names displayed on r since i can look at them easily on excel. What I am trying to do is isolate each sheet from the excel file and assign object names to them so I can get summaries/stats for each sheet independently then proceed to get stats/summaries for all sheets combined. Each sheet is an experiment and I am trying to get summaries/stats for them essentially.

Comment: @LogeDoge : Each of the "leaves" in the `alldata` structure is a full-fledged dataframe. You can use any descriptive function, eg that from Hmisc, with this  call`lapply(alldata, Hmisc:describe)`

Comment: Technically LogeDoge, none of the names are displayed in R. The point of this was to do exactly what you said you wanted: make each sheet available as a frame. The fact that it's a list of frames might be a new thing, but it works very well in some situations (such as when they are all identical or similar structure and/or you will be doing the same thing(s) to each, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227).